# Adding border to entire grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have a `grid` with **three rows and columns**. I am trying to **set border** for this grid. For that i tried:

```
<Grid Height="405" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Margin="130,100,0,0" Name="Grid" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="405" Opacity="0.5">
</Grid>
```

I am creating `rows and columns and their content programmatically.`

**Problem:**

If i set border inside Grid then it will be for one row. If i set border outside grid then it goes to the entire window. I am setting border with:

```
<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black"></Border>
```

Is there any way to set border for the grid like in html: if

**HTML:**

```
<table style="border:1px solid #000;">
```

it will set border for entire table.

Comment: Please show us an image of the result you **do not want** and the result that you **do want**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put the grid inside the border:

```
<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Grid Height="405" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,100,0,0" Name="Grid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="405" Opacity="0.5">
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: I tried but it is setting for my entire window...When i set this no border comes for my grid but it is setting for my window

Comment: @user3262659 "entire window"? Really? Wrap the whole lot in a stackpanel, duplicate the new `Border` (and child `Grid`) and see what happens. You should be two borders. The `Border` element is _not_ like style in html. It is an entity all of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Place a outer Border which will acts as a parent for that Grid and you can style that border as your wish..

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF000000" Height="405" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="405">
    <Grid Name="Grid" Opacity="0.5"/>
</Border>
```

Make sure that the things you wish to apply for the Grid, apply that to the `Border` so that it acts exactly as you expected...